# com.google cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, protocols, protocol-buffers

I am trying to to work with protocol buffers for my first time. I have been following the steps in the code below (this is for an android application):
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-dataAndroid/?ca=drs-#resources
However, I cannot seem to get it to work. Since my own coding didn't work, I decided to try and use the source code provided... well this is when I run into the problem that I was having with my own code. I get.. "com.google cannot be resolved to a type" for situations like the one below. Please help! I have been stuck trying to get this protocol buffer sample to work for days now. Thanks!

```
 public static final class Quote extends
  com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage {
// Use Quote.newBuilder() to construct.
private Quote() {
  initFields();
}
```

Comment: Does this have anything to do with App Engine?

Comment: Did you not read the README? *You will still need to download the source code package in order to obtain the
Java or Python runtime libraries.  Get it from:
  https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/*

Answer (score 1):

Well this answer is for a situation related to something like this.

Please make sure that the version of protobuf **runtime's** dependency that you add to your project is **exactly** same as that of the **compiler** that you installed.

In my case as I was using maven, so I used the following dependency for compiler version -3.0.0

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

To read about compiler installation you can refer:
https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the code/class/JAR that contains `com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage` is on your classpath when compiling your code.